# Can not understand the sequence of method and constructor

Tags: java, uml

According to sequence diagram I should create firstly method "regisreItem(Item item)" with argument "item" as an object. I see my problem that the constructor for "items" is called after the method "regisreItem(Item item)" so that I have nothing to insert into "regisreItem(Item item)" method according sequence diagramm. Or not ?

Sequence diagram

[image]

Class diagram

[image]

Here is a part of sequence diagram i am interested in

[image]

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eJolWNoN32IubP3iaaXPc_cLM5Es08hK
Here is all my sort of code.

Please provide me some sort of code ho is it possible to implement.
And clarify the beginning of sequence diagram.

Comment: Voted to close since it's just the SD being wrong and thus not understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the operation `registerItem`  expects an item as parameter, the Auctioneer object needs to create it, before calling the operation. That means the Auctioneer has to send a create message, not the Auction (using `new Item()` as a parameter is not possible in a sequence diagram - and it doesn’t change the creator anyway). `i1` and `i2` are attributes of the interaction. They can be used as parameters of `registerItem`.
`addBid` also expects a `bidder`. Again the attributes `Max` and `Moritz`of the interaction should be used here.

In a real program these interaction attributes would be temporary variables of the `Auction::addBid` operation or of the Auctioneer. The Auctioneer is probably not supposed to have variables, therefore the `registerItem` Operation should probably only have generic data types such as `string`as parameters.

The `Auction` is supposed to send messages to `i1` and `i2`, however, since these are attributes of the interaction, the `Auction` object does not know them. It’s Ok to omit this detail, but it would be better to show how the `Auction` finds the relevant `Item`, for example with a `findItemByName` Operation called on itself.

A better alternative is, to let the `Auction` send the messages to its own attribute `allItems`. Then two lifelines would represent the same attribute, but with different objects. A selector could be used to distinguish between the two objects in the slot defined by this attribute (`allItems[0]`, `allItems[1]`, this is optional). The same is applicable to `allBids` instead of `b300EUR` and the like.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around the issue of the Item constructor being called after registerItem by using:

```
registerItem(new Item(...));
```

and passing in the attributes of Item `i1` and `i2`. That will create the new Item and then it can be added to the auction Item list.

I'm assuming the start of the sequence diagram is the auctioneer creating or opening an already created auction and then adding a list of items that will be used in the auction by repeatedly calling `registerItem(new Item(...));` which can then have bids added to them by Max and Moritz via the `Auction` object

Comment: Okay thanks, I have inderstood, but it seems for unclear how could I create i1 item through registerItem(new Item(...)), that would be called i1 actually. How can I name my new object i1?

Comment: Perhaps registerItem(new Item("item1", "an item desc", 200)); then in the registerItem method, this will come in as a created item `item` so you could just say `list.add(item)`. that will add the item to the list.

Comment: I have not understood what do you mean by "200e"?

Comment: and sorry about that, I pressed enter not realizing it would post instead of going onto a new line. I'm pretty new here

Comment: I mean how could be new object as i1 named, I understand that it is possible to insert attributes inside the constructor, but actually I need also to call a new object some how. For example normally constructor is called so: Item item1=new Item("item1", "an item desc", 200). And in this code "registerItem(new Item("item1", "an item desc", 200))" I do not understand how could I name object as "item1"

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas for now

Comment: Even when written like this you still technically call the constructor before calling `registerItem`. The sequence diagram is most probably wrong.

Comment: Yeah that's true actually, didn't think about that still calling the constructor.

Comment: The SD is defective for sure, `register..` expects an `Item`
 which must be present before.

Comment: Thanks everyone, i will try to get explanation from my teacher. Because i share the same opinion